# How to add multiple source in one class in puppet manifest and how to declare that?

Tags: puppet

```
class practice_oracle
{
$files_inst = [
/tmp/packages/compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-47.3.x86_64.rpm,
/tmp/packages/elfutils-libelf-0.125-3.ML5.x86_64.rpm,
/tmp/packages/elfutils-libelf-devel-0.125-3.ML5.x86_64.rpm,
/tmp/packages/gcc-4.6.3-2.fu2012.x86_64.rpm,
/tmp/packages/gcc-c++-4.6.3-2.fu2012.x86_64.rpm,
/tmp/packages/glib2-2.28.8-1.fc15.x86_64.rpm,
]
file {
$files_inst:
ensure => present,
owner => root,
group => root,
mode => 0755,
source => "puppet:///modules/practice_oracle/compat-libstdc++-33-32.3-47.3.x86_64.rpm",
source =>puppet:///modules/practice_oracle/elfutils-libelf-0.125-3.ML5.x86_64.rpm",
source => "puppet:///modules/practice_oracle/elfutils-libelf-devel-0.125-3.ML5.x86_64.rpm",
source => "puppet:///modules/practice_oracle/gcc-4.6.3-2.fu2012.x86_64.rpm",
source => "puppet:///modules/practice_oracle/gcc-c++-4.6.3-2.fu2012.x86_64.rpm",
}
```

In this code I m try to write multiple source and then I run on agent machine but when running this script on agent machine then it take the same size for all the packages whichever first in the list.
so what code write for this script and what are the mistakes in this my code. 
Please help me for that question.

Answer (score 3):

The way you are going about this will not work. However, the `file` type does have a `recurse` option for use with directories. You can use this as follows:

Example

```
file { '/tmp/packages':
  ensure  => directory,
  source  => 'puppet://modules/practice_oracle",
  owner   => 'root',
  group   => 'root',
  mode    => '0755',
  recurse => true
}
```

This will populate the `/tmp/packages` directory with the entire directory contents of `${::modulepath}/practice_oracle/files`.

Reference

https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#file-attribute-recurse

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case: what ptierno said.

Generally, create a utility defined type:

```
define remote_file($dest_dir='/tmp/packages', $module='practice_oracle') {
    file {
        "$dest_dir/$title":
            ensure => present,
            owner => root,
            group => root,
            mode => 0755,
            source => "puppet:///modules/$module/$title",
    }
}
```

And just

```
remote_file { $file_inst: }
```

Comment: Heyy.felix Please tell me the installation of packages on red hat.

Comment: I m try to install the oracle packages on red hat 6 but it could not install.It gives me an error -could not find rpm

Comment: @akshay If you are facing issues while installing `rpm` packages from files on `RHEL` through `puppet`, you should post a question on ServerFault or SuperUser.